# Sequential Events on JavaScript for on Function

Tags: javascript, sequence

For video player, there are 3 actions: `play`, `pause` and `continue`. For `continue` action, it is defined as `play` after being `pause`.

If I have 2 functions already defined for `play` and `pause`:

```
videoPlayer.on('play', function () {
      //play video
});
videoPlayer.on('pause', function () {
      //pause video
});
```

I am having trouble defining the sequential action of `pause` -> `play`. Would the below function work for `continue`?

```
videoPlayer.on('pause').on('play', function () {
       //Continue video           
})
```

Comment: How is `on` defined? It looks like it could be jQuery, which has a distinct methodology for creating new events, such that it would be as easy as `videoPlayer.on('continue', function () { ... });`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use promises to wait till the video is paused

```js
function playP() {
    videoPlayer.on('play', function () {
        //play video
    });
}

function pauseP() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        videoPlayer.on('pause', function () {
            // do stuff
            res(true);
        });
    })
}

pauseP().then((x) => {
    if (x) 
        playP();
})
```

This code will wait till the video is paused to start listening for the `play` event.